# Import multiple .csv files into single spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, csv, import

I'm working on a simple macro to take all the csv files from a folder and copy the data into a single worksheet. All the csv files are formatted the same with headers and used data in columns a:f. The macro will open each file in turn, but nothing is getting copied. I also tried bypassing the copy/paste and still get nothing. Any ideas??

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportData()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim clastrow As Long
Dim filePath As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim count As Long
Dim importRange As Range
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim cws As Excel.Worksheet

count = 0

Set cws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw_Data")

filePath = "C:\Users\christopher.huiett\Desktop\csv_folder\"
fileName = Dir(filePath & "*.csv")

Do While fileName <> ""
    count = count + 1

    Set wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath & fileName)
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    clastrow = cws.Cells(Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Set importRange = ws.Range("a2" & lastrow)           'skips header row

'    cws.Cells(clastrow, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(importRange.Rows.count, importRange.Columns.count) = importRange.Value

    importRange.Copy

    cws.Cells(clastrow, "a").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    wb.Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wb.Close

    fileName = Dir

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? I can't see anything wrong, after you set your `importRange` does it have the address that you need? Does `clastrow` get the value that you expect? Does your code run, or do you get errors?

Comment: oh debug shows that  ws.Range("a2" & lastrow) = <automation error>. So it's never getting copied. Gotta change to ws.Range("a2:f" & lastrow).....thanks! Stupid mistake.

Comment: Now I've seen your error, let me get you the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error comes here:

`Set importRange = ws.Range("a2" & lastrow)`

If `lastrow = 25` then that means:

`Set importRange = ws.Range("a2" & 25)`

which is: `ws.Range("A225")`

So you need to change it for this:

`Set imporRange = ws.Range("A2:F" & lastrow)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you problem is the line `Set importRange = ws.Range("a2" & lastrow)`. Consider that lastrow = `1000`: You would set the importRange to `A21000` - a single cell that is for sure empty.

While the use of `UsedRange` is often not the method of choice when you want to figure out how many rows/columns are in use: When opening a workbook, it is reliable. You want to skip the first row, so you can use simply use `UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)`. This will copy a blank line at the end, but that does no harm.

```
clastrow = cws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Set importRange = ws.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)
```